# [UICollectionViewCell cellImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, selector, uicollectionviewcell

on an UICollectionView I want to populate the CollectionViewCell with images. But I get the following Error:

Where is my error and how can I fix it?

```
2013-01-29 22:25:38.606 foobar[1277:c07] CollectionViewController loaded with searches: 22
2013-01-29 22:25:38.609 foobar[1277:c07] id: 0 -> content: <UIImage: 0xaa618e0>
2013-01-29 22:25:38.610 foobar[1277:c07] -[UICollectionViewCell cellImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x939a7b0
2013-01-29 22:25:38.610 foobar[1277:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell cellImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x939a7b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d9f012 0x139fe7e 0x1e2a4bd 0x1d8ebbc 0x1d8e94e 0x478a 0x7e9a1a 0x7eb034 0x7ed2d1 0x33792d 0x13b36b0 0x2afffc0 0x2af433c 0x2af4150 0x2a720bc 0x2a73227 0x2a738e2 0x1d67afe 0x1d67a3d 0x1d457c2 0x1d44f44 0x1d44e1b 0x1cf97e3 0x1cf9668 0x2e765c 0x24dd 0x2405)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

The code which causes the error is following:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *myCell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:Cellid forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int row = [indexPath row];

    NSLog(@"id: %d -> content: %@", row, [self.searches objectAtIndex:row]);

    myCell.cellImageView.image = self.searches[row]; // <-- Signal SIGABRT
    return myCell;
}
```

The code for UICollectionViewCell is the following:

### CollectionViewCell.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageView;

@end
```

### CollectionViewCell.m

```c
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation CollectionViewCell

@synthesize cellImageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Show us where you register your custom subclass for a certain reuse identifier, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please make sure, that you set the custom class `CollectionViewCell` for the cell in Interface Builder.

Comment: That was the problem :) Found it as well.

Comment: Fine - if it was the correct answer, I would appreciate, if you would accept it then. This is basically the way, this site works. Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh. Didn't know that. With accept you mean vote? Or where do i have to do that?

Comment: Click on the checkmark left to the answer. More detail in the FAQ in the section [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: I have the same error but still not working after i set the right custom class in IB. What else could it be ?

Comment: If you are still having the issue after adding your custom cell, its because you are registering the default cell in viewDidLoad.  Remove the registerClass method.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the class: `CollectonViewCell` to Collection View Cell in Storyboard (Identity Insepector). After that and reassigning the `IBOutlet` `cellImageView` it worked!

Comment: You should accept @SAE answer since that helped you, rather than repeating the same here.

Comment: Was a time issue. Figured it out by myself and when i start writing it sae's post was not yet there... It was not the intention to repeat it.

Comment: I just mentioned since I saw that when it is sorted by Oldest tab, his answer was appearing before yours. Also saw your comment on his answer. So thought I will just let you know that in case you are not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:Cellid forIndexPath:indexPath]` you are not being returned a cell that belongs to your custom collection view cell subclass, but a standard `UICollectionViewCell`. This suggests to me that maybe something is off at the point at which you register your cell with your container view. It's probably going to be helpful if you post that code as well.

Comment: `UICollectionViewCell`, not `UIContainerViewCell`. Also, yes, it'll be the way he's registering for the certain reuse identifier. As you (and I) have said though, to answer the question we need to see that code.

Comment: There comes a certain point in the evening where one shouldn't post to SO without double checking everything! Thanks.